# Fullscreen applications and games randomly minimize or go out of fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, virus, fullscreen

It is of course impossible to play any game because it always looses focus and gets minimized. Or if I watch a movie in fullscreen then in about 10 second interval the fullscreen is leaved and I have to reenter it every 10 seconds...

How can we find out what is responsible for this? Is it a virus?

Comment: These 3 apps should help identify the process: Window Focus Logger (http://www.adminscope.com/downloads/), WinLister - (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winlister.html) and WinExplorer (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winexp.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it tomorrow and report back.